# MySQL Errcode: 13 - Permission denied

Tags: mysql, windows, permissions, windows-10

I'm using MySQL 5.7.10 and [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/) to handle my database migrations. Everything works fine on Linux and Mac but on Windows 10 I am getting this error:

```
Error on rename of '.\mydb\#sql-1da0_a.frm' to '.\mydb\proc_error_table.frm' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

This is part of the SQL in question causing the error:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `proc_error_table`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `error_import`;

CREATE TABLE `proc_error_table` (
  `procedure_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `sql_state` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `sql_message` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `error_timestamp` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

create index idx_proc on proc_error_table(procedure_name);

#
# This is the line causing the error.
#
create index idx_file_id on proc_error_table(data_set_file_id);
```

I tried explicitly defining a tmpdir with sufficient privileges but that didn't work:

```
tmpdir = C:/temp
```

I tried to give explicit FULL ACCESS to the data FULL ACCESS to the MySQL Data directory but that didn't work:

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data\mydb
```

I tried changing the user that MySQL runs as to my personal account and that didn't work.

Something, somewhere is preventing MySQL from gaining access to this directory and or file(s). The Windows Event Log, nor the MySQL show any indications as to what is preventing it.

What tool can I use to figure this out?

Comment: Are you running the `FlyWay as run as Administrator` ??

Comment: @Mr.Arjun, Yes I am running Flyway as Administrator also.

Answer (score 3):

it could be a conflict with antivirus software. try to turn it off

Comment: In my case, this solved it. I think the antivirus was locking files or something, which mysql wasn't having any part of.